# performSelector queue & runloop schedule

Tags: nsrunloop, performselector, ios-multithreading

I have read apple's code example [ListAdder](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ListAdder/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010275) about how to use NSOperation. [Technical Note TN2109](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2109/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010274-CH1-SECTION3) also explains the details.

If there is already an Operation calculating, and the user delete a data by remove a cell from the tableview, then the tableview delegate method will be called and tiggers new Operation to recalculate. I have drew a diagram to show this:

[diagram shows the call sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDaiZ.jpg)

question:

1.M1,M2,M3 will always be processed in one single loop?

2.function `adderOperationDone` was send to main thread to be executed via the `performSelectorOnMainThread` function, i know the selector will be added to the mainRunloop's queue, but when the queued will be executed?

3.Is there any circumstances that the `M4` is inserted between `M2` and `M3`?